# Rails: Class in same module not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a problem. I am new to Ruby, so I am struggling with some issues, which I can resolve after a couple hours, but this one is bugging me for a day now.

I created a class in `/lib/math/calc.rb` with the following content:

```
module Math
    module Calc
        class << self
            def check!(value1: nil, value2: nil)
                raise Error.new(message: "value1 is required") unless value1
                raise Error.new(message: "value2 is required") unless value2
                Divide.send!(value1: :value1, value2: :value2)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Then I also have a class `Divide` which is located in: `/lib/math/calc/divide.rb`, with the content:

```
module Math
    module Calc
        class Divide
            class << self
                def send!(value1: nill, value2: nill)
                    # More code here
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Now when I call: `Math::Calc.check!(5, 5)`, I get the following error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Math::Calc::Divide
```

I already tried inserting `require 'divide'`, but those imports do not exist he said.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Tip: Instead of the `class << self` dance you can just write `def self.check!`.

Comment: Did you `require` the other file? `require_relative './divide` for example. If you're working outside the scope of the Rails autoloader it might not load these for you. `lib` is not an ideal place. `app/concerns/math` is a better place to put this.

Comment: Ah, yeah I wanted it to act like a gem component, but keep it local, thats why I put it in `/lib`

Comment: That creates a lot of problems, especially that it won't be automatically reloaded, so you'll need to keep starting and stopping your Rails server. If you want to take advantage of what Rails offers, put it in `app/concerns` with whatever name you want. If you want a gem, often better to make it an actual gem outside of the control of the autoloader,  though in this case you'll need to be disciplined about `require`.

Comment: Okay so just move it in `app/concerns` and put the require in the class and it should work. I can don't need to restart my application when I change code in my class. What is being autoloaded then, because code gets reloaded while application stays running?

Comment: It is still not working. I put the entire `math` folder from `/lib` and placed it in `/app/concerns`. I also added `require 'math/calc/divide'` in the `math/calc.rb`. This require statement does not fail, but it still gives me: `NameError: uninitialized constant Math::Calc::Divide`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ensure you have `math.rb`, `math/calc.rb` and `math/calc/divide/rb` all located within `app/concerns`. Then the autoloader can make sense of it. At that point no explicit `require` calls are necessary.

Comment: unfortunately rails don't include current directory you have to use require_relative

Comment: Yes @tadman, its working now!

Comment: @tadman I vehemently disagree that `/concerns` is a good place for this code. Concerns in general is a wishy washy Rails term for "a module thats used as a mixin in your models/controllers". This code is a wierd module and a class thats used as a module.

Comment: @max Rails has a lot of strange conventions, and this is one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Rails [the autoloader](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#config-autoload-paths) has the following root directories:

- Any subdirectory of `/app`.
- `/app/controllers/concerns`
- `/app/models/concerns`

A root directory (aka an autoloading path) is a directory where the autoloader will look for root level constants.

So you can "fix" the problem by moving your code into an existing root directory.

But since the constant `Math` is already part of the Ruby core referencing may not actually cause the autoloader to load the constant. This can create issues with the classic autoloader but not Zeitwerk which has a map of your constants. You should seriously consider here if you want to monkeypatch a core class with a very questionable addition (don't do it). In general if it isn't your namespace keep your grubby little nubbies away.

`/lib` is intentionally not autoloaded. It is assumed that you'll explicitly require the code there when needed. You can if you want to add `/lib` to the eager and autoloading paths.

```erb
module MyApplication
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # I don't actually recommend this.
    config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
    config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
  end
end
```

Then there is really the issue that this code is just bizarre and buggy and just not Ruby.

If you want to make keyword arguments required then make them required:

```
module Calc
  def self.check!(value1:, value2:)
    Divide.send!(...)
  end
end
```

But its unclear why you would even want to use keyword arguments on the other end. The arity of division in a functional function is always two (`divide(x, y)`) and one in an object oriented method (`x.divide(y)`). While the use of keywords is generally bettter then having a lot of positional argument - if you give them meaningless names you're making the code needlessly verbose and harder to actually use.

But ultimately this code is just very un-rubyeske because in Ruby you perform operations such as division by sending an object the message `:/, number`.

```
10/2
```

This calls the method `/` on Integer.

If you want to explore how to actually write a calculator I would instead write something like:

```
class Calculator 
  def initialize(val)
    @val = val
  end

  def /(y)
    self.class.new(@val / y)
  end
  alias divide /

  def +(y)
    self.class.new(@val + y)
  end
  alias add + 

  def cos
    self.class.new(Math.cos(@val))
  end 
end
```

```
puts Calculator.new(10) / 2 # =><Calculator:0x0000557b2526e238 @value=5> 
operand, y = :/, 2
puts  Calculator.new(10).send(operand, y) # =><Calculator:0x0000557b2526e238 @value=5> 
# Since the methods return a new instance you can chain the method calls
puts (Calculator.new(10)/2).cos # => <Calculator:0x0000557b24e1e598 @val=0.28366218546322625>
puts Calculator.new(10).divide(5).add(2).cos #=> <Calculator:0x0000557b24ba97b8 @val=-0.6536436208636119>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna do it using plain Ruby you just need to require the `Divide` file inside of your module, so the intepreter knows where the file is located

File tree:

- lib/math/calc.rb
- lib/math/calc/divide.rb

```
# lib/math/calc.rb
require_relative 'calc/divide'

module Math
  module Calc
    class << self
      def check!(value1: nil, value2: nil)
        raise Error.new(message: "value1 is required") unless value1
        raise Error.new(message: "value2 is required") unless value2
        Divide.send!(value1: :value1, value2: :value2)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Aside from that: note that you don't have the `Error` class defined in there. You also are not actually sending the proper values to `Divide.send!`. In order to do it you should send `Divide.send!(value1: value1, value2: value2)`

Answer (score -2):

Maybe try the below.

lib/math/calc.rb

```
module Math
  module Calc
    require_relative './calc/divide'
    extend self

    def check!(value1: nil, value2: nil)
      raise Error.new(message: "value1 is required") unless value1
      raise Error.new(message: "value2 is required") unless value2
      Divide.send!(value1: :value1, value2: :value2)
    end
  end
end
```

lib/math/calc/divide.rb

```
module Math
  module Calc
    class Divide
      def self.send!(value1: nill, value2: nill)
        # More code here
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Also, maybe create your lib directory inside your app e.g `app/lib`

Comment: Don't stuff `require_relative` inside of `module` definitions. This makes it very hard to, at a glance, understand what a given file is dependent on.